# How to detect Heteroscedasticity in Random Foreest Model?

Tags: r, random-forest

I am working on a regression model in Random Forest, I want to judge whether there is heteroscedasticity in the model or not?

When I am developing Linear Model I can see that there is heteroscedasticity and the curve looks like below graph, I want to check similar residual plot for Random Forest Model.

I am working in R.

[It's an Expense Model basis Income,Branch,TotalFamilyMember](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EiSpR.png)

[image]

Comment: You may be able to recreate the plot by differencing `myfit$predicted - mydata$y`, where "predicted" is the model fitted values and "y" is the response variable. More details from you will definitely help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can recreate the plot with the residuals from the predicted values:

```
#Using the regression example from ?randomForest
ozone.rf <- randomForest(Ozone ~ ., data=airq, mtry=3,
                         importance=TRUE)

#Find residuals by subtracting predicted from acutal values
err <- ozone.rf$predicted - airq$Ozone

#Make data frame holding residuals and fitted values
df <- data.frame(Residuals=err, Fitted.Values=ozone.rf$predicted)

#Sort data by fitted values
df2 <- df[order(df$Fitted.Values),]

#Create plot
plot(Residuals~Fitted.Values, data=df2)

#Add origin line at (0,0) with grey color #8
abline(0,0, col=8)

#Add the same smoothing line from lm regression with color red #2
lines(lowess(df2$Fitted.Values, df2$Residuals), col=2)
```

[image]

**Update**

There is a much easier way. I realized that the plot is just a regression of residuals and fitted values, therefore this gives the same output:

```
fitted.values <- ozone.rf$predicted
residuals <- fitted.values - ozone.rf$y
plot(lm(residuals ~ fitted.values), which=1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your detail explanation.

Comment: One thing I am unable to understand from updated answer of yours the fitted values axis is not coming correct, any reason for this though the graph is symmetrical.

Comment: The internals of "lm" handle the axes in their own way. The first method allows you to control the output more.